# How can I create or update the database schema from models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema, models

I have to create or update a schema from some models that I have changed in rails. 
The original schema file it's wrong because of some changes I have done in the models.

I want to know what can I do (if possible) to create a schema and a migration FROM THE ACTUAL MODELS (based on the "belongs_to", "has_many"... etc tags).

Thanks beforehand!!!

Comment: Are you looking to only create foreign key reference columns (via the associations in the model)? The models won't show ordinary attributes corresponding to table columns unless they're mentioned in validations, methods, etc.

Comment: I'd generally recommend writing and running the migrations before making any changes to the models, not afterwards. If the changes to models are already made, I'd write the migrations manually, otherwise how can I be sure that my database schema is exactly how I want it?

Comment: I want to create a n:n relation between 2 tables (a post has many tags and a tag has many post). The point is: In the schema appear a field in the post table pointing to tags. However, in the tag table doesn't appear a field pointing to posts.

Comment: You need to create a third table for that, posts_tags, and a has_and_belongs_to_many association between the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many